# Check via VBA if file exist on a sharepoint site

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I just want to check if a file already exist in a sharepoint. I used a Boolean Function that worked perfectly at the begining but since a short periode it doesn't work anymore!!

this is what i wrote:

```
 Public Function checkFile(URLStr As String) As Boolean

Dim oHttpRequest As Object

If Len(Trim(URLStr)) = 0 Then checkFile = Empty: Exit Function
Set oHttpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
With oHttpRequest
    .Open "GET", URLStr, False ', [UserName], [Password]
    .setRequestHeader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
    .setRequestHeader "Pragma", "no-cache"
    .send
End With
If oHttpRequest.Status = 200 Then
    checkFile = True
Else
    checkFile = False
End If
Set oHttpRequest = Nothing

End Function
```

Here the mistake is at the point.  **.send** 
I don't understand why and i don't find another solution to check if a file exist since the file is in a sharepoint site.

Comment: Can you show us an example value of the `URLStr` parameter passed in to the `checkFile` function?

Comment: URLStr: https://sec-ishare.infineon.com/sites/MC_PM/Shared%20DDocuments/09_Reporting/PT\2016/PT PM Weekly 20170330.pptm